# Can a 24.0VDC/3.0A Power Supply be used with a breadboard?

Tags: power-supply

I came across a DZ075 power supply.  It says it is +24.0V/3.0A.  Can that be used with a breadboard?  Or do I have to get it to 3.3V or 5V before I plug into the breadboard.  In other words, can it be plugged into the board then make it 5volts or before?

I took the cover off and found there are 8 pins.  The last three are +24V, the middle three say ground, GND, and the first two are not connected, but the pins available and say +5v.

I do not wish to be electrocuted or destroy stuff.

Edit:  Here is a picture:

[image]

Edit:  Could I move the connector all the way over to the left?  It would be connecting two 5V, three GND, and one 24V (the connector is only six connections).

Edit:  I'm not sure I should use it.  The amps are high.  From this calculator, http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2007/09/20/wire-parameter-calculator/ it looks like my 23AWG wire is too small.

Comment: It also says +5V. Could it be a solution for your breadboarding?

Comment: @AliChen I am hoping it is.  What about the 3A part?

Comment: what about "3A"? According to summary datasheet, https://psui.com/wp-content/uploads/products/Tri-Mag/DataSheets/dz075.pdf you have DZ075-9 model. The table says 24V3A and 5V0.5A. Breadboarding generally requires more attention to details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breadboard itself (assuming the usual plastic boards full of holes) doesn't care what voltages you use on it - however, the circuit you are building DOES care.  If you are working with common digital ICs, then you need a 5 volt (or possibly 3.3 volt) power supply.

If you are working with other types of circuits - an audio power amplifier, for example, you may need 24 volts, or +/- 15 volts, or something else.

If your circuit wants 5 volts, you could build a votlage regulator on the breadboard to reduce the 24 volts from your supply to the 5 volts your circuit requires, but it may be easier (and safer) to buy a 5 volt "wall wart" supply.

Comment: You mean like the MB102 or something similar?

Comment: Yes - the MB-102 is what I assumed you meant by "breadboard".

Answer (score 1):

Look through the internet, you will find pinout. Here's what I found [here](https://surplusway.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_79&products_id=3894)

Output:

<s>Pin1,2 = +3.3V === 6A</s>

Pin3,4 = COM

Pin5,6 = +5V === 4A

Pin7 = -12V === 0.6A

Pin8 = +12V === 2A

**Edit**: thanks for posting the picture. It is not that one I found :P

I guess if something wrong will happen to breadboard, manufacturer will be refusing from warranty obligations because you did not use *recommended* power supply (if such was recommended by them). Thus think twice before re-using it.

Comment: I added a picture.  I don't think it is the same one.